# API documentation console unsuccessfully tries to load MiniProfiler results

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

All of the documentation pages ([example](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers)) with the test console currently attempt to load MiniProfiler result data, which fails with a 404:

```
POST https://api.stackexchange.com/mini-profiler-resources/results 404 (Not Found)
```

If that result information isn't meant to be available, those pages should just not load the MiniProfiler resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed in the latest deploy.

Comment: I'm gettin the same error in my own application. This is preventing me from using MiniProfiler. Could you share whatever you did to fix this?

Comment: @DanielLidström I just disabled miniprofiler on production for the API, there's no "user session" so there's no reason to push down results.  Nothing fancy.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it on my part. Turned out I had done a simple, stupid mistake.